# React-Alert-template-mui : The above error occurred in the <WithStyles(ForwardRef(Dialog))> component:

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

Basically Whenever I Click the Button The Error is Occured and Everything is working perfectly fine. but this error occur in react-alert-template-mui library. Because When I switch the library to react-alert-template-basic then error is gone..

app.tsx

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { positions, Provider } from "react-alert";
import AlertMUITemplate from "react-alert-template-mui";

const options = {
  position: positions.MIDDLE
};



export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (

    <Provider template={AlertMUITemplate as any} {...options}>


      < Component {...pageProps} />

    </Provider>
  )
}
```

index.tsx

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'
import { Button } from '@mui/material'
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {

  const alertShow = useAlert();

  const alertClick = () => {

    alertShow.show("hello");

  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={`${styles.main} ${inter.className}`}>


        <Button onClick={alertClick}>Click me</Button>


      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```